# How to make navigation drawer apear below actionbar?

Tags: java, android, drawer

I know this question has been asked before but it seems like in the newer versions of AndroidStudio something has changed. Eitehrways, the old solutions don't seem to work or I am doing something wrong.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homescreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_homescreen_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DrawerLayout` is above the App Bar in the layout, therefore it draws over it.

You need to do something like:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
...
>

<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homescreen"
        ...
        />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...>

... rest of your XML layout

</DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This will allow the `App Bar` to be drawn "on top" of the nav drawer

Comment: Oh that worked. The reason it didn't before when i tried was because android:fitsSystemWindows was set to true!